# extract number from \jobname as counter

Tags: macros, counters, xstring

I want to use a part of the filename as a counter:

First I try to use a variable as a counter:

mwe_aa_03.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\newcommand{\thatispage}{3} 
\addtocounter{section}{\thatispage} 
\ihead{Page \thatispage }  
\begin{document}
\section{section}
but this should be section 3
\end{document}
```

this works, but now I want to use the filename as a number:

mwe_bb_03.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\fancypagenumber}{\StrBehind[2]{\jobname}{\string_} }
\addtocounter{section}{\fancypagenumber}
\ihead{Page \fancypagenumber }  
\begin{document}
\section{section}
but this should be section 3
\end{document}
```

which does not work ("Missing number, treated as zero").

Can you explain what I am doing wrong? How can I make this string becomming a number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two errors.

1. You can't use `\StrBehind` inside the argument to `\setcounter`
2. You need to set the counter to one less than the number you want, because `\section` steps it before typesetting the title.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xstring}

\StrBehind[2]{\jobname}{\string_}[\fancypagenumber]

\addtocounter{section}{\fancypagenumber}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
\ihead{Page \fancypagenumber }

\begin{document}
\section{section}
but this should be section 3
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative without packages, you can make a command gobble the part that you want leaving just the number. Note that you need to use `\detokenize{..}` because of the category codes of the `\jobname`.

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\removemewbb\detokenize{mwe_bb_}{}
\edef\fancypagenumber{\expandafter\removemewbb\jobname}
```

Comment: My filename changes from time to time. I only know for sure that the two dashes are there, and the number I want is in the third/last part for now. Therefor I will use the xstring code this time, but thanks for another intressting approach.

Comment: Also possible, but I understand that you use another solution. This definition would work `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\removeuntilsecondunderscore#1\string_#2\string_{}}\x` and then `\edef\fancypagenumber{\expandafter\removeuntilsecondunderscore\jobname}`.